# How do I simulate anonymous classes in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, anonymous-class

I'm writing a small data structures library in C#, and I'm running into an architectural problem. Essentially I have a class which implements the visitor pattern, and there are many possible implementations of visitors:

```
public interface ITreeVisitor<T, U>
{
    U Visit(Nil<T> s);
    U Visit(Node<T> s);
}

public abstract class Tree<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public readonly static Tree<T> empty = new Nil<T>();
    public abstract U Accept<U>(ITreeVisitor<T, U> visitor);
}

public sealed class Nil<T> : Tree<T>
{
    public override U Accept<U>(ITreeVisitor<T, U> visitor) { return visitor.Visit(this); }
}

public sealed class Node<T> : Tree<T>
{
    public Tree<T> Left { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Tree<T> Right { get; set; }

    public override U Accept<U>(ITreeVisitor<T, U> visitor) { return visitor.Visit(this); }
}
```

Anytime I want to pass in a visitor, I have to create a visitor class, implement the interface, and pass it in like this:

```
class InsertVisitor<T> : ITreeVisitor<T, Tree<T>> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public T v { get; set; };

    public Tree<T> Visit(Nil<T> s)
    {
        return new Node<T>() { Left = Tree<T>.empty, Value = v, Right = Tree<T>.empty };
    }

    public Tree<T> Visit(Node<T> s)
    {
        switch (v.CompareTo(s.Value))
        {
            case -1: return new Node<T>() { Left = Insert(v, s.Left), Value = s.Value, Right = s.Right };
            case 1: return new Node<T>() { Left = s.Left, Value = s.Value, Right = Insert(v, s.Right) };
            default: return s;
        }
    }
}

public static Tree<T> Insert<T>(T value, Tree<T> tree) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return tree.Accept<Tree<T>>(new InsertVisitor<T>() { v = value });
}
```

I don't like writing that much boilerplate code, because it gets very messy when you have a non-trivial number of visitor implementations.

I want to write something similar to [anonymous classes Java](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3300881/The-Essence-of-OOP-using-Java-Anonymous-Classes.htm) (concept code):

```
public static Tree<T> Insert<T>(T v, Tree<T> tree) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return tree.Accept<Tree<T>>(new InsertVisitor<T>()
        {
            public Tree<T> Visit(Nil<T> s) { return new Node<T>() { Left = Tree<T>.empty, Value = v, Right = Tree<T>.empty }; }
            public Tree<T> Visit(Node<T> s)
            {
                switch (v.CompareTo(s.Value))
                {
                    case -1: return new Node<T>() { Left = Insert(v, s.Left), Value = s.Value, Right = s.Right };
                    case 1: return new Node<T>() { Left = s.Left, Value = s.Value, Right = Insert(v, s.Right) };
                    default: return s;
                 }
            }
        };
}
```

**Is there any way to simulate anonymous classes with interface implementations in C#?**

Comment: Might want to explain what an anonymous interface is. I'm afraid I have no clue what it means.

Comment: @Noldorin: anonymous *interface* isn't the best choice of words, what I mean was anonymous *class*. There's a feature in Java where you can implement interfaces on the fly without needing a named class -- I'd like to do something similar in C#.

Comment: You sure you can't make do with delegates?

Comment: In C#, anonymous types cannot implement interfaces.  See here for more information:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this right, but instead of a visitor interface, could you make a visitor base class with the common logic?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508853/c-feature-request-implement-interfaces-on-anonymous-types

Comment: @Juliet: stop smoking F#

Comment: @Mauricio: Guilty as charged ;) I'm actually trying to write an immutable data structures library in C#, maybe even start an open source project on Google code, and I'm using F#'s programming idioms as my baseline. Anonymous classes are useful because they keep all the tree traversal logic contained in the same method and (at least superficially) resembles pattern matching.

Comment: @Juliet: how about http://code.google.com/p/functional-dotnet/ http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BclExtras

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could change the "behavior" part of the class from methods defined against an interface to delegates called at the appropriate time, and create a new visitor by passing new delegates -- thereby enlisting anonymous functions to do the work of anonymous classes.

Sketch code (not tested, you can clean up as appropriate):

```
class CustomVisitor<T> : ITreeVisitor<T, Tree<T>> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public T v { get; set; };
    public Func<Nil<T>,  Tree<T>> VisitNil  { get; set; }
    public Func<Node<T>, Tree<T>> VisitNode { get; set; }

    public Tree<T> Visit(Nil<T>  s) { return VisitNil(s);  }
    public Tree<T> Visit(Node<T> s) { return VisitNode(s); }
}

public static Tree<T> Insert<T>(T v, Tree<T> tree) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return tree.Accept<Tree<T>>(new CustomVisitor<T> {
        VisitNil  = s =>
            return new Node<T>() { Left = Tree<T>.empty, Value = v, Right = Tree<T>.empty }; }
        VisitNode = s =>
        {
            switch (v.CompareTo(s.Value))
            {
                case -1: return new Node<T>() { Left = Insert(v, s.Left), Value = s.Value, Right = s.Right };
                case  1: return new Node<T>() { Left = s.Left, Value = s.Value, Right = Insert(v, s.Right) };
                default: return s;
             }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1, +answer: oh wow, that was simpler than I thought :) I was worried that would need to re-write my code using `if (tree is Nil) { ... } else { ... }` just to keep all the tree traversal logic contained in the same method. Much appreciated!

Comment: This is a good example of how functional programming concepts can add value to object-oriented languages. =)